# How to pickle NotImplementedType

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, deep-copy

How do you add support for pickling traditionally non-pickablable types in Python?

I have a complex object I need to pickle, and it include references to the class `NotImplementedType`. The class is third-party, so I can't override its `__copy__()` or `__deepcopy__()` or `__getstate__()` methods.

I'm not entirely sure why Pickle can't serialize NotImplementedType. I'm sure there's some silly dogmatic reason, which I don't care about. The fact is that this class doesn't ever change, and contains no state, so it should be serializeable. And sure enough, the [dill package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) can serialize this class just fine.

So I tried to implement a custom [copy_reg](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy_reg.html) handler for `NotImplementedType` that uses dill like:

```
copy_reg.pickle(NotImplementedType,
   lambda code: (dill.loads, (dill.dumps(code),)),
   dill.loads)
```

However, attempting to deepcopy my object throws the exception:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

from line 347 in `/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py`. Diving into this code shows that the copy_reg/deepcopy/pickle modules expect to serialize and deserialize instances, not references to classes, and it's throwing this exception because it's trying to instantiate `NotImplementedType` instead of just looking up the class reference. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: I just tried pickling NotImplementedType in Python 3.6, and it just happens, with no errors. (NotImplementedType obtained as `ref = type(NotImplemented)`)

Comment: And on the other hand, I can confirm your error in Python 2.7

Comment: Have you tried explicitly pickling with protocol 2? The default pickle protocol on 2.7 is 0, and it lacks support for a number of features of new-style classes (and even when it works, it's absurdly inefficient on both time and space). Protocol 2 natively supports new-style classes, it's faster, smaller, and handles many things protocol 0/1 can't handle at all.

Comment: Ah, never mind. I thought `NotImplementedType` was some special third party thing, looks like it's just `type(NotImplemented)`. It doesn't work with any protocol on Py2, and it works with all protocols on Py3, where it grew a specialized `__reduce__` that basically `pickle`s it so as to call `__builtin__.type(__builtin__.NotImplemented)` on deserialization.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly unlikely the class in question actually contains `NotImplementedType`; rather, it probably is pickling `NotImplemented`, and the reduction function for `NotImplemented` is trying to pickle it in terms of its type, but `NotImplementedType` isn't exposed directly (you can only get it via `type(NotImplemented)`), so the attempt to make a qualified name that can find `NotImplementedType` fails. This is fixed in Python 3 (another argument for moving), but it looks fairly simple to fix in Python 2 as well, as defining a normal `copy_reg` handler for `NotImplementedType` will ensure `NotImplemented` is pickled without referencing its own type.

The easy way to do this is to have your reducer function return the string naming `NotImplemented`, which will then be looked up as a global when unpickled. Conveniently, this means you don't need to define any helper methods (that might not exist on the unpickling side):

```
copy_reg.pickle(type(NotImplemented), lambda obj: 'NotImplemented')
```

You don't define a constructor (the third `copy_reg.pickle` argument) at all; the pickle will contain all the information needed to recreate `NotImplemented` without any dependencies on the unpickling side, getting `NotImplemented` back without ever trying to serialize `NotImplementedType`.

Comment: And yeah, I just checked the CPython source code. In Py2, there is no special `__reduce__` defined for `NotImplemented` (it [has a custom `repr`, nothing else](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l20460)), but in Py3, it [explicitly defines `__reduce__` to return the string `"NotImplemented"`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/object.c#l1483), exactly as in my `copy_reg` solution. So the `copy_reg` approach is exactly equivalent to what Py3 does.

Comment: With this solution I still get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: @IvanCastellanos: You get the error with what? The OP didn't even provide a code sample, so you could be running anything. I can tell you that running the exact code in my answer (after importing `copy_reg`) makes `NotImplemented` round trip picklable on Python 2.7 (while not performing the registration makes it die with `TypeError: can't pickle NotImplementedType objects`), but I can't begin to guess what might be wrong with your code. The test is pretty trivial (`pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(NotImplemented))`, swapping to `cPickle` for the accelerated test).

Answer (score 1):

The [`copy_reg.pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy_reg.html#copy_reg.pickle) function explicitly allows a function that returns a string. In case it's a string it will use the string as name to "lookup" (see also the [`__reduce__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__)):

```
import copy_reg
copy_reg.pickle(type(NotImplemented), lambda x: 'NotImplemented')
```

And this will allow to copy (and pickle) `NotImplemented`:

```
import copy

>>> type(copy.deepcopy(NotImplemented))              # still a NotImplementedType object
NotImplementedType

>>> copy.deepcopy(NotImplemented) is NotImplemented  # and still the same object!
True
```

Comment: I was editing this in as you posted, sigh. Caught the string behavior while rereading to make sure I hadn't missed a better solution. Ignore this, misread: <s>Your demo code is wrong though; it should produce `NotImplemented`, not `NotImplementedType`.</s>

Comment: @ShadowRanger I used `type` on the return value of `deepcopy` so it should be `NotImplementedType` but I also added another example that it's still the same "global" even after deepcopy.

Comment: Ah, whoopsy. That's what I get for skimming. Yeah, that's right. This does assume the third party class isn't actually storing `NotImplementedType` itself in the instances, but it would be extremely weird if it did so.